# Invalid sql statement: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code:

```
$connection = new DBConnection();
$searchDeals = false;
try {
    $sql = 'SELECT d.`id`, d.`title`, d.`user_id`, d.`deal_price`, d.`original_price`, d.`host_link`, d.`coupon_code`, d.`description`,
                    d.`start_date`, d.`expire_date`, d.`votes_counter`, d.`created_at`,
                    u.`username`
            FROM `deals` AS d
            WHERE d.`title` LIKE :search_input
            JOIN `users` AS u
            ON d.user_id = u.id
            LIMIT :max_deals
            OFFSET :pageOffset';
    $stmt = $connection->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':max_deals', $maxDealsInPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pageOffset', $pageOffset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'search_input' => '%' . $_GET['q'] . '%' --- HIGHLIGHTED LINE ---
    ));
    $searchDeals = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
} catch(PDOException $e) {}
$connection->disconnect();
```

I get this error message:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens ON LINE (---HIGHLIGHTED LINE IN MY CODE---)
```

I can't understand why.. because I do supply all required tokens...

Comment: why do you not bind the params in the same way?

Comment: I count 3 parameters: search_input, max_deals and pageOffset. But you only provide 1 (I think  you can not mix binding, provide all via execute or bind them all one by one).

Comment: @Frieder in fact, OP binds 2 parameters using `bindParam()` and the last one using `execute([])`

Comment: Try binding them all via `$stmt->bindParam`, rather than mixing the approaches. Apart from anything else, it makes the code more readable and consistent. It's unclear why you randomly included one parameter via the execute() method instead.

Comment: @Cid: you can not mix it, there you go: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php `If the prepared statement included parameter markers, either PDOStatement::bindParam() hs to be called OR an array of input-only parameter values has to be passed`. OR is the important operator.

Comment: @Frieder Yes.. I did the 3-rd param now with `bindParam` and it worked.. Didn't know I can't mix

Comment: @Frieder indeed, I just pointed the fact OP *tried* to bind them all

Comment: @QwertTrewq but why did you mix them in the first place? It makes the code messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix binding of parameters. I quote from the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> Execute the prepared statement. If the prepared statement included
>   parameter markers, either:
>
> ```
> PDOStatement::bindParam() and/or PDOStatement::bindValue()
> ```
>
> has to be called to bind either variables or values (respectively) to the
>   parameter markers.
>
> **OR**
>
> an array of input-only parameter values has to be passed

So just use `bindParam()` for all three parameters or provide them all via `execute()`